# Ho do I send a message to whomever closed my question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I have a question on [Ho do I add a new paragraph or new line in Dictation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457367/ho-do-i-add-a-new-paragraph-or-new-line-in-dictation) which asks about adding paragraphs to dictaion on macOS. It was closed because there is a different question regarding other punction on the iPhone at [Is there a NATIVE way to add punctuation using Dictation on an iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458760/is-there-a-native-way-to-add-punctuation-using-dictation-on-an-iphone).

As far as I’m concerned the two questions are unrelated, and should never have been associated. The question should never have been closed without an attempt to clarify whether the other question is in any way relevant.

I have added comments to my question accordingly, but I’m not sure that the closer will get the point. Is there a way to make the point directly to the closer?

Comment: You don't. You are not supposed to contact people that participated in closing the question. If you want the question to get reopened you must convince the **reviewers** that the question is not a duplicate. You do this by editing the question and showing how the suggested answers do not apply. Don't address voters and do not include any meta-commentary.

Comment: The edit you added is inappropriate and should be rolled back. A question should not have any meta-commentary. Don't talk about the other question. When your question gets reopened, the edit becomes outdated. Your audience is not interested in what you think of the other question.

Comment: Question closure is not normally a unilateral action.  A consensus of users close a question, you need a consensus to reopen.  (Addressing a single user is irrelevant.  There is of course the exception of moderator or gold badge holder action.)